# Is the preimage of a closed set closed?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. Can I prove if $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is closed then so is $A^{-1}(S) =\{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : Ax \in S\}$

What I am thinking is that I can't, based on my knowledge that if $x \subseteq \mathbb{R}^m$ is closed, its linear transformation $ Ax \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is not always closed, because what I assume is when dealing with the first case, $x \in A^+S$, where $A^+$ is the pseudo-iverse of matrix $A$, which is another linear transformation.

Comment: How much topology do you know? Also, $A^{-1}(S)$ is the set-theoretic preimage of $S$. It is defined regardless of whether $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @carmichael561 Sorry I know little about topology

Comment: What is your definition of closed then?

Comment: If the closed sets are the complement of the open sets, you know the linear mappings in finite dimension are continuous, and if $U^c$ is a closed set then you have $A^{-1}(U^c)=A^{-1}(U)^c$ which is closed since $A^{-1}(U)$ is open.

Depending of how much do you know about the topology of the euclidean spaces, and the definition you use, there are a lot of ways to prove what you want.

The proof that linear mappings are continuous is given in a course of vector calculus.

Comment: @carmichael561 I used the definition that if every convergent sequence in a set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ converges to a point in $C$, then $C$ is closed.

Answer (score 2):

For a function $A\to B$, the preimage of a closed set is closed provided that function is continuous. Every linear transformation $\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is continuous, and has a matrix representation. You can conclude that the preimage of any closed set under a linear transformation is closed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is closed since $A$ is continue and the inverse image of a closed subset by a continuous map is closed.